# 25,5 тыс. человек — прочтение

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, числительные

Для меня естественно только такое прочтение: *двадцать пять с половиной тысяч человек*. Но я часто встречаю *"тысячи"* вместо *"тысяч"* (то же с млн, млрд и другими подходящими под этот случай числами, а также предметами или существами).

Конечно, этому есть объяснение. Выходит, те, кто так пишет, имеют в виду *двадцать пять и пять десятых тысячи человек*. ***Но насколько такое прочтение естественно и нет ли рекомендаций избегать его или по возможности выбирать первое?*** Конечно, всё возможно, возможно даже то же относительно последнего (ну мало ли!), но мне кажется, что странно "считать десятые", там где можно оперировать половинками. Да и в математике 5/10 сокращается до 1/2, поэтому 1/2 (то же, что половина) лучше воспринимается.

Answer (score 1):

25,5 тыс. неважно кого/чего должны быть прочитаны как *двадцать пять и пять десятых тысяч**и**.*

(Что написано, то и читаем!)

Диктор (журналист, репортёр, ведущий), глядя на бегущую строку, волен выбирать вариант. В меру своей испорченности/продвинутости. Ведь никто, кроме него, не видит написанного.

Не будь столь масштабной цифры, я бы посоветовала ***пишущему***  всегда отображать цифирь словами, но с тысячами, миллионами и миллиардами этот номер не проходит...

Предлагаю паллиатив (душою оставаясь верна трём начертанным сверху строкам):

*25 с половиной тысяч человек.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Галина!

Comment: Рад стараться, гражданин начальник!

Comment: )))))))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

Язык не математического уровня (или каких-либо иных точных наук), а обыденный, свободен в воспроизведении дробных чисел устной речью. И десятичных, и простых. Слова *половина, четверть, треть* не только упрощают восприятие на слух больших величин, но и говорят, что приводимые большие числа не отражают достоверные — с точностью до десятка или единицы — данные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я рад поддержке!) Так чем Вы считаете форму с пятью десятыми: ошибкой или просто допустимым, но неудачным вариантом?

Comment: Нужна в точных науках и допустима для педанта, который говорит «конеЧно».

Comment: Всё-таки Вы не ответили: ошибка или нет?)

Comment: Если цифры абстрактны (изустно оглашён порядок жизней), как, скорее всего, в Вашем примере (двадцать пять с половиной тысяч человек), то — правильно. Если речь о точной цифре (ровно 25,5 тыс. чел.), что характерно, к примеру,  только для условий в арифметической задачке, тогда не ошибка, так как задача требует... точного ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо) У меня, правда, произнесение с десятыми не связывается с большей точностью. Если бы я хотел отметить точную цифру, то сказал бы "ровно двадцать пять с половиной тысяч" или "ровно двадцать пять тысяч пятьсот человек".

Answer (score 0):

Итак, **двадцать пять и пять десятых тысячИ человек**.

Конечно, так не стоит читать:  длинное число воспринимается на слух с трудом,  "двадцать пять с половиной тысяч" звучит понятнее.

А если "двадцать пять и шесть десятых тысячи человек"? Тут уж придется читать по правилам. И тогда возникает вопрос: а почему "тысячи",  а не "тысяч"?

Да и в математике  желательно уметь правильно называть дроби, например: **десять целых и семь десятых метрА, двЕ целые и три пятых метрА.**

Проверить же правильность окончания можно, подставив пропущенные слова "целая единица" и "доля":

**десять целых** (целых единиц) **и семь десятых** (долей) **метра**, **две целые** (целые единицы) **и три пятых** (долей) **метра**.

Comment: Спасибо, Жасмин! Только Вы неправы насчёт 2,6 м: должно быть *дв**А** и три пятых метра*. Ведь "метр" мужского рода.

Comment: Артем, а вы уверены? Посмотрите ответ по ссылке https://otvet.mail.ru/question/48577187. Там процент - тоже м. рода.

Comment: Со словом "целых" конечно двЕ. Т. е. либо "две целых и три пятых метра", либо "два и три пятых метра". С десятами совсем короткая форма будет "два и шесть метра" (при этом опускаем десятые, и "метра" подчиняется конечно же по-прежнему шести десятым).

Comment: Возможно. Но мне кажется, что при корректном чтении дроби в математике слово  "целых" надо произносить обязательно. Иначе получается разговорная (упрощенная) речь. Ответ я исправлю. Вот еще ссылка на тему http://gramota.ru/forum/veche/69945/